# Entity Framework 6 WithMany and derived types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I use a child/derived class in a collection in a navigation property and setup the appropriate constraints in Entity Framework 6?

Considering this model:

```
// Base class
public abstract class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int WidgetId { get; set; }
    public virtual Widget Widget { get; set; }
}

// Child classes
public class Consumer : Person { ... }
public class Supplier : Person { ... }

// Compositing principal class
public class Widget 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Consumer> Consumers { get; set; }
}
```

Widget has a one-to-one relationship with a `Supplier`, and a zero-to-many relationship with `Customer`.

How do I configure the `Consumer` relationship with inheritance in mind?

My attempt so far:

```
public class PersonSchema : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person> 
{
    public PersonSchema() 
    {
        ...
        HasRequired(p => p.Widget)
           .WithMany(w => w.Consumers) // INVALID CAST
           .HasForeignKey(p => p.WidgetId);
           ...
    } 
}
```

I have trimmed out code for brevity, but I feel this illustrates where the problem is.

The problem is with the WithMany as this is of type `ICollection<Consumer>` and it is expecting `ICollection<Person>`.  And you can't just chuck a cast in front of it.

Comment: You painted yourself in a corner. For a 1:1 association Widget-Supplier, when Widget is the principal, Supplier has to copy its Id from Widget. However, for the 1:n association Widget-Consumers, Consumer can (and probably should) have an auto-incrementing Id column. EF(6) can't map both types of keys in one inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: This is why the Person base class has a Foreign Key to Widget.  It references the Widget primary key, and has its own Id identity column.

If the Widget only has a collection of Person, then it works fine, but that loses the appropriate type for the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this can't be done.  I had to create WidgetId explicitly in Consumer and Supplier.  Bit of a dirty fudge to get EF to work.